# Twilio conversations push notifications not working - Empty Credentials error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, twilio, twilio-api

I need to enable push notifications in my project. I have already integrated twilio conversations.

I followed [this documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/javascript/push-notifications-web) and seems to be ok, but there is a problem with the `setPushRegistrationId` method.

I have this code:

```
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";
import initFirebase from "../firebase/initFirebase";

export const handleNotifications = async (conversationClientInstance) => {
  const app = initFirebase();
  const messaging = getMessaging(app);
  getToken(messaging, {
    vapidKey:
      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  })
    .then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log("currentToken", currentToken);

        //Here is the problem <----------
        conversationClientInstance
          .setPushRegistrationId("fcm", currentToken)
          .then((el) => console.log("el", el));
        onMessage((payload) => {
          conversationClientInstance.handlePushNotification(payload);
        });
      } else {
        // Show permission request UI
        console.log(
          "No registration token available. Request permission to generate one."
        );
        // ...
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
      // ...
    });
};
```

I am getting this error on the twilio dashboard:

[image]

I also replicated this situation **[in this github repo](https://github.com/Tricabit/twilio-conv-test)**. It is deployed, so you can try it live.

In console I can see the FCM token, but `setPushRegistrationId` returns **undefined** (the `console.log('el', el)`)

I think I forgot something, but I can't figure out what. What do you thik?

Comment: The [`setPushRegistrationId` function](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/2.1.0/docs/classes/Client.html#setPushRegistrationId) resolves to `void` so it is expected that your log there is `undefined`. I tried your deployed version and didn't see anything logged from the `handleNotifications` function. Can you confirm that you have set the correct credential sid in your chat grant? The error description suggests it can't be found within your account (20404).

Comment: hi @philnash! I think I I did something wrong at step3. I don't get that error message anymore. But also I don't see any changes. The browser asked the permission to enable notifications. What should I do next in order to see some changes?

Comment: It's good you're not getting that error any more, that must mean you have the creds right now. If the browser is asking permission, that's also a good sign! Sounds like you've done everything right now. Can you send a message to a user that has registered for notifications? What happens? Can you log from inside the `onMessage` callback to see if it's being called?

Comment: I tried to log the `payload` of `onMessage` but it doesn't write anything... on the guide they use the previous version of firebase and they invoke the method through `firebase.messaging()`while I use the next version and I import it directly, but I don't think it's a problem. Should I see the payload on the other client when I write a message?

Comment: Using the latest and importing correctly shouldn't make a difference. I think we're onto a different question from the original one you asked. It might help to ask a new question specifically about receiving incoming push messages and share the relevant code and what is happening now.

Comment: yes, you're right